# How to create a Lookup field in a Visualforce Page?

Tags: visualforce

I am developing a Visualforce Page and I want to render a lookup field in the same page.

So, I am attaching the page to my Custom Controller (Say AdminController) and I want to create a lookup field to User object.

I am new to salesforce, so any kind of help would be appreciated.

I have written my custom Controller

```
public class AdminController{
   public User usr {get;set;}

   // creating dummy method
   public String getUser() {
        return null;
    }

     public AdminController()
    {
       usr= new User();
    }
}
```

And in my Visualfolce Page I have entered

```
<apex:inputField value="{!usr.id}" />
```

Comment: what code have you tried so far ?Please post the code .Also we found no attachment.Instead of any attachment paste the code directly .Thanks

Comment: @MohithKumar: I have entered the code.

Comment: Is it your standard controller or custom controller?And do you have any lookup field on the object you have your controller?

Comment: @MohithKumar: "AdminController" is my Custom Controller and AdminSetting is my Custom Object where I am having a field (UserRefference) with lookup to User.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public with sharing class AdminController {

  public AdminSetting__c adsetting { get; set; }

  public AdminController {    
    adsetting = new AdminSetting__c();  
  } 
}
```

The below is how your visualforce tag should be

```
   <apex:inputField value="{!adsetting.user_ref_field__c}" />
```

Please note i dont know your API names of object and field so you need  to make sure to replace with exact names

Comment: @MohitKumar: It is working Fine. I should have instantiated my custom object inside my Custom Controller.

Comment: @MohitKumar: I want to create a lookup field to PageLayout. But as I know there is no standard object named as 'Page Layout'.

Comment: you mean you want to pull all layouts of an object?Please post as different query.You will need to use describe calls

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create lookup field in visualforce page, it should be lookup field in the querying object.

So create lookup field on your object realated with **user** and use it in vf page