# Lookup in visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, lookup

It's possible to create a lookup in visualforce page to choose one of two visualforce pages with the data from object?

I have one object, and I have to choose one pdf or another according the value choosed in picklist?

I appreciate your help.

Comment: try this link "http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/20840/how-to-create-a-lookup-field-in-a-visualforce-page".., "http://sfdchack.blogspot.in/2013/01/salesforce-custom-lookup-using-apex.html"

Comment: welcome to salesforce.stackexchange user8715. Your questions is a bit confusing to me (could just be me thoug), could you maybe add some more detail, or maybe show us what you've already got?

Comment: Hello Samuel De Rycke

I've got
2 visualforce pages rendered PDF.

When I create a new record I have a button create pdf to a visualforce page, and in this new window I have to choose in a lookup or link lists, which visualforce page I want and send me to new pdf, but with the information from record.

Comment: What have you done so far? If you share what you have written, maybe someone can help out.

Comment: Just maked the visualforce page with table, rendered pdf.

Let me see if I can explain better.

After I create a record I can choose between 2 different pdf type.

So I have a button Pdf, but inside this button I have to choose 1 of 2 pdfs. 

And this is my problem I don't know how create this part

Comment: Do you want to re-render/switch the page by using the picklist?

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating a custom button, set the content source to URL then you can use a formula to set up your conditions and resulting pages... /apex/pdfPage1?id={!MyObject__c.Id}

Comment: The URL doesn't work

IF(ISPICKVAL(tipo__c, "X"),
/cs20.salesforce.com/apex/page1?={!Invoice__c.Id},
IF(ISPICKVAL(tipo__c, "Y"),
/cs20.salesforce.com/apex/page2?={!Invoice__c.Id}))

Comment: you don't need the cs20.salesforce.com, just have the /apex... that way it will work in test and production environments. If you want to hardcode the instance then start with http://cs20...